# before-change event is not trigged when I click "go back" button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks, page-caching

environment:
`rails4.01 + turbolinks2.0 + jquery`

browser:
Chrome, Safari 7.0

goal:
when user changed content in form page and leave (not saved), I will prompt them.

my solution

```
$ ->
  $(document).on 'page:before-change', ->
    confirm 'Are you sure you want to leave this page?'
```

problem:
when I click other links in browser page, it works well. 
if I click 'go back' button belongs to browser, `page:before-change` is not triggered, how to fix issue in this case.

Comment: try the event `page: fetch`

Comment: @emaillenin, thanks a lot, the feature I am working on is that notice editor text changed before they reload/leave the page.